# In telegram i want bullet points , numbering and indentations but its not working

Tags: markdown, telegram, telegram-bot

I need to format my text in telegram.
I try to use markdown language for the following text:

```
* Item
* Item
```

It prints the text as it is.
It is supposed to print bullets instead.

I am following this link: https://wordpress.com/support/markdown-quick-reference/

Answer (score 10):

This will not help you with indentations but will make nicely looking bullet points. Just copy and paste the [bullet point UTF-8 character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2022) at the beginning of each line.

• first point
• second point
• etc

[image: screenshot from telegram]

Comment: Tip: If you put two spaces behind each point, StackOverflow won't put them in one line and make a nice list instead

Comment: actually I had to put space `after` each line, but it totally worked, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Telegram's versions of MarkDown: [Markdown](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style) & [Markdown v2](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style) don't support any sort of lists.

The only way to achieve this is using the *pre-formatted code block* with a 'custom' list which will allow any sort of indentation:

````
```
1) Item - 1
2) Item - 2
    A) Sub-Item - 1
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've used circle bullets for my lists  -( • &#8226;)